# How many screws are used to mount a custom panel on Bosch 800 plus dishwashers?

Tags: dishwasher

... I only see 4 holes - two at the top, two near the middle (vertically). Is that it or are there additional locations?

Comment: What do the instructions say? Can you post a photo of the panel or the dishwasher itself? Thanks!

Comment: Instructions say "refer to template" which I don't have and bosch does not provide online. Will post photos shortly